# postgresql: выделить домен первого уровня из адреса

Tags: регулярные-выражения, postgresql

подскажите как выделить домен первого уровня из адреса в postgresql (через регулярное выражение)

нужен именно домен первого уровня, т.е. чтобы для

```
https://www.one1.two2.you-tu_be.com/watch?v=PyEYtwpKrfI&t=872s
```

получить

```
you-tu_be.com
```

вот такой же запрос выделяет просто домен

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING(link, '(?<=://)([^/]+)'), '^www\.', ''), link from tbl
```

Comment: Возможно стоит от обратного идти. Не делать замену, а найти что-то вроде `(\.[^.]*){2}$`, т.е. домен первого уровня (.com) и второго (you-tu_be), потом точку в начале убрать.

Comment: Развернуть задом наперед, выделить домен и развернуть обратно

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать MATCHES вместо REPLACE `select REGEXP_MATCHES('https://www.one1.two2.you-tu_be.com/watch?v=PyEYtwpKrfI&t=872s', '(?<=://[^/]*)[^\./]+\.[^\./]+(?=/)')`